# Using regex with find

Tags: terminal

I need to move all files that start with `iCloud` and of `.zip`extension (using find).
After reading several pages on regex, I still cannot seem to make it work.

This is the output:

```
~/Downloads$ find -E . *.zip
HP_Easy_Start.app.zip
OneDrive_1_09-04-2022.zip
OneDrive_2022-05-04.zip
OneDrive_4_08-04-2022.zip
WhatsApp Unknown 2022-04-27 at 19.25.32.zip
iCloud Photos-2.zip
iCloud Photos-3.zip
iCloud Photos.zip
t.0.zip
logo.zip
```

Now, when I attempt any combination starting with `^iCl` it does not work. I get:

```
~/Downloads$ find -E . ^i                                                     1
find: ^i: No such file or directory
```

Any reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need `find -E . [stuff]` to tell `find` to search in the current directory: `find` requires the path to search as an argument. Then `[stuff]` should also be modified: the documentation for `find` says

```
 -E      Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex
         primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions...
```

So you need to include `-regex`. Then it says

```
 -regex pattern
         True if the whole path of the file matches pattern using regular
         expression.  To match a file named "./foo/xyzzy", you can use the
         regular expression ".*/[xyz]*" or ".*/foo/.*", but not "xyzzy" or
         "/foo/".
```

So `^i` will not match anything: the paths will be of the form `./iCloud...` So you could do `find -E . -regex "./iC.*"`. If you have lots of directories and subdirectories — for example, if you're doing this from your home directory, with `Library`, `Music`, `Pictures`, and other directories with lots of entries, you might also want to add `-maxdepth 1` to prevent the search from going into those directories.

Comment: Thanks @john-palmieri ! I edited my question to show the correct syntax.

Comment: For simple filename patterns, I'd use `-name`, which takes a glob pattern instead of a regex, and only matches the name, not the entire path. For example, `find . -name "iCl*"`. In any case, it's critical to quote the pattern, so the shell doesn't expand it before passing it to `find` (as it did with `*.zip`).

Comment: If you want to be sure the shell doesn‘t interfere use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson and nohillside ! I will surely try this as well.

Comment: Now, my question being, how do it I tell find to retrieve the ones beginning with "iCloud" and ending with ".zip"? I understand that the current iCloud files are all .zip, but what if there were other extensions?

Comment: @mariano-daniel `find . -name 'iCloud*.zip'`. BTW, replace `-name` with `-iname` if you want case-insensitive matching, e.g. to also match "icloud-something.ZIP"

Comment: Thanks again @GordonDavisson! Sorry for the super obvious question, but when something starts going wrong with regex, I tend to get scared and bail. Thanks!

Comment: @mariano-daniel It's also important to understand the distinction between glob (aka wildcard) patterns and regular expressions, which are just different enough to be very confusing. [This Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globbing-and-regex-so-similar-so-different) summarizes some of the differences.

Comment: As @GordonDavisson says, glob patterns are usually simpler to use than regular expressions. If you really want a regular expression version, then `find -E . -regex '[.]/iCloud.*[.]zip'` should do it.

Comment: reading the Journal @GordonDavisson, many thanks again! Your help is always very valuable!